# After importing does not see the library

Tags: android, android-layout

After importing next problem, does not see the library as I understand.Tell me how to solve the problem

[image]

Again, I imported the project, now Screen is not quite empty but not full

[image]

**aaa Sorry decided I did not put the settings**

Comment: What does your edit mean? Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you do the import? I'm not too sure I understand your project structure. Do you have an available JAR file of the library you need? If you do, create a `/libs` folder in your Android app. Build the project and the import should be available.

If you are importing a library project, right click on your main project, choose Properties then Android then under Libraries, add the library project you need.